# Is it right to offer prayer with naked neck for women?

Tags: salat, practical-islam

i have heard from some one that rolling of hair on head (making jura) and make naked neck is not right for women while offering prayer?

Answer (score 1):

It is not right for women to expose their necks in prayers since any part of the body, except for the face and hands, should be covered as it is considered 'Awrah; otherwise, they should repeat their prayer due its specified time.

[See the Fatwa here](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatwa/33711/a-woman-should-conceal-the-area-between-her-neck-and-chin-in-prayer)

The scholars mentioned that the Wudu has to include washing the face which is permitted to be revealed in Salah. The face limits start from the forehead till the chin passing by the two sides in front of the ears. Its name in Arabic is "وجه" which means "واجهة" and "interface/exposure" in English which indicates that the face with its **exact** limits is what is allowable to be uncovered in Salah knowing that the neck is not a part of the face limits according to the scholars interprestion of the verse which says:

> ...wash your faces...

[*Verse 6 — Surah Al Ma'idah*](http://www.alro7.net/ayaq.php?langg=english&aya=6&sourid=5)

Unfortunately, I didn't find the [saying of the scholar](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/121534/) in English, but once I find it, I will attach it here (or if anyone can find it).

> **قال الشيرازي**: ثم يغسل وجهه وذلك فرض **لقوله تعالى**: فاغْسِلُواْ وُجُوهَكُمْ. والوجه ما بين منابت شعر الرأس إلى الذقن ومنتهى اللحيين طولاً، ومن الأذن إلى الأذن عرضاً.

He stated the face limits that to be exposed in Salah as they are washed in Wudu as a part of the valid and correct Wudu procedure in Islam.